# How to avoid data-display of hex values in the PHPMyAdmin UI

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, lamp

[image]

I am using the LAMP stack setup (Ubuntu-16.04, Apache2, Mysql5.6, PHP7.2). My MySQL version is 5.7.33. I am using PHPMyAdmin for accessing the database. In one of the databases, in some tables, the information is appearing like hex values instead of regular texts. Is there any configuration (in PHPMyAdmin/MySQL) so that I can view those values as regular values.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the data type of that field?

Comment: The datatype is varbinary

Comment: I'm afraid I'm having trouble reproducing this. Could you please tell me more about how you've inserted the data initially and what the exact literal data that was inserted should be?